# How to replace blanks based on another data frame entry in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R:

```
df <- structure(list(a = c("siamese", "siamese", "siamese", "chow", 
"chow", "chow"), b = c("", "cat", "cat", "", "dog", "dog")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

> df
        a   b
1 siamese    
2 siamese cat
3 siamese cat
4    chow    
5    chow dog
6    chow dog
```

How do I fill in the blanks based on the other entries that are the same?  So it looks like this:

```
> df
        a   b
1 siamese cat   
2 siamese cat
3 siamese cat
4    chow dog
5    chow dog
6    chow dog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `sqldf()` to generate distinct combinations of `a` and `b` and merge them back into the original data.

```
df <- structure(list(a = c("siamese", "siamese", "siamese", "chow", 
                           "chow", "chow"), b = c("", "cat", "cat", "", "dog", "dog")), class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(NA, -6L))

library(sqldf)
lookup <- sqldf("select distinct a, b from df where b != ''")
df <- subset(df,select = -b)
merge(df,lookup)
```

...and the output:

```
> merge(df,lookup)
        a   b
1    chow dog
2    chow dog
3    chow dog
4 siamese cat
5 siamese cat
6 siamese cat
>
```

Answer (score 0):

in Base R

```
df[df$b=="",]$b <- unlist(lapply(df[df$b=="",]$a, function(x) head(df[df$a==x & df$b!="",]$b,n=1)))
```

output

```
 df
        a   b
1 siamese cat
2 siamese cat
3 siamese cat
4    chow dog
5    chow dog
6    chow dog
```

Answer (score 0):

Group data by `a` and fill missing values of `b` with `fill()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(b = na_if(b, "")) %>%
  group_by(a) %>% 
  fill(b, .direction = "updown") %>% 
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   a       b    
#   <chr>   <chr>
# 1 siamese cat  
# 2 siamese cat  
# 3 siamese cat  
# 4 chow    dog  
# 5 chow    dog  
# 6 chow    dog
```

`.direction = "updown"` means filling `NA` first up and then down. You can choose `"downup"`, `"up"`, or `"down"` according to your case.

Answer (score 0):

We can group by 'a' and get the `first` non blank element in 'b'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(a) %>% 
   mutate(b = first(b[b!=""]))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   a [2]
#  a       b    
#  <chr>   <chr>
#1 siamese cat  
#2 siamese cat  
#3 siamese cat  
#4 chow    dog  
#5 chow    dog  
#6 chow    dog
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(b = if_else(b == "", NA_character_,b)) %>% 
  fill(b, .direction = "up")


        a   b
1 siamese cat
2 siamese cat
3 siamese cat
4    chow dog
5    chow dog
6    chow dog
```